# OpenERP 7 : How can I make a field editable in a inheriting view?

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo

I made a view inheriting a tree to add a field (date_encaissement) in it, but I want this field to be editable in the tree view, I know that it is done by adding editable="top" or "bottom" in the tree and then adding readonly="False" in the field, but here I was asked to not modify the inherited view. So I have to put the "editable" attribute somewhere in my view but I don't know where.

Here is my view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="receipt_dates_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">receipt.dates.tree</field>
            <field name="model">account.voucher</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_voucher.view_voucher_tree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <xpath expr="/tree/field[@name='amount']" position="after">
                        <field name="date_encaissement" readonly="False"/>
                    </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath` attribute directly in the `tree` node itself.

```
<xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="editable">top</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Your view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="receipt_dates_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">receipt.dates.tree</field>
            <field name="model">account.voucher</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account_voucher.view_voucher_tree" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="editable">top</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="/tree/field[@name='amount']" position="after">
                    <field name="date_encaissement" readonly="False" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

After that, you could use the `readonly` attribute if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **attributes** to achieve this. 
Here is an example for you.

```
<record id="testing" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.inherited.view</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/tree" position='attributes'>
            <attribute name='editable'>bottom</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Regards,